# Lightning: How the edit page title is formed in lightning?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, edit

I'm experiencing the following difference of the Lightning behaviour between two environments. In one of the environments when I edit a Lead record it pops up the edit page and its title is 'Edit Lead'. In the other environment on edit the page title is 'Edit {Last Name}' e.g. 'Edit Smith'.

If any of you noticed such behaviour. Could this be related with the date of the environments creation or the edition of the environments.

I want to stick with Salesforce Lightning but cannot understand where these differences come from and which is the correct behaviour.

**EDIT**

I observe the standard Salesforce Lightning behavior when I override the standard 'new' and 'edit' pages with my VF pages. Doing this I do not use any custom pages or modifications. I need the standard Lightning behavior. I'm testing Lightning using two different orgs with sys admin user (desktop pc). One of the orgs is professional edition and the other one is developer edition.

What I noticed is that in the professional edition on edit the page title is 'Edit {Last Name}' and in the developer edition the page title is 'Edit Lead'.

My question is why there is difference between the orgs. How to determine where this kind of differences could be observed. Would this be unified in the future.

Comment: You mention 2 environments. Do you mean two orgs, 2 computers, running in Classic vs Lightning or something else? Are you using different profiles? What's unique from one to the other? Is there a custom page involved in one of the environments, a Lightning Component, or Mobile device? You've not told us enough to be able to help you. Please visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your response and clarification. Here are more details about my question.

I observe the standard Salesforce Lightning behavior as I want to be maximum closer to it when I override the standard 'new' and 'edit' pages with my VF pages. Doing this I do not use any custom pages or modifications. I need the standard Lightning behavior.

I'm testing Lightning using two different orgs with sys admin user (desktop pc). One of the orgs is professional edition and the other one is developer edition.

Comment: Just to make certain here, do you have any 3rd party apps installed to manage leads or lead conversion in either of the orgs?

Comment: No, I haven't any 3rd party apps installed. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, you say you're overriding the std new & edit pages with your own VF pages in these orgs. What fields are you displaying in these custom (non-standard) VF pages? Those changes will propagate to Lightning. From you description, it sounds like they're doing it differently in PE than in DE.  If these aren't custom pages & you don't have code, please provide a screen capture of the edited VF page setup for each org.

Comment: It seems like there is a misunderstanding of my question. Let start from the beginning. I have registered two free trial accounts one dev and one professional - no custom staff, no modifications and no 3rd party apps installed. It comes about Lightning. In the professional edition on edit the page title is 'Edit {Last Name}' e.g. Edit Smith and in the developer edition the page title is 'Edit Lead'. I want to mimic the standard Salesforce page - styles, behavior, everything. So my question is which is the correct behavior? What causes the difference? Would this be unified in the future? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Lightning Experience, your detail pages should be edited in the Lightning Control Panel's Lightning Page editor (under Objects), NOT in the Visualforce Page Editor. Generally speaking, the Professional Edition is on parity with Enterprise Edition (equivalent to what you'd see in a Developer Edition) with the exception that API access is not enabled for customers (i.e, no ability to create or run custom Apex). However, you should be able to edit pages in either Lightning or Visualforce. But, you'll want to edit them in the environment you will be using. I recommend you edit your pages in LEX to see if the difference in behavior you're seeing still exists.